# How to dockerize a golang web app with maven like structure

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I have a hard time dockerizing a web app with following structure:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
├── file3.txt
├── go.mod
└── src
    ├── go
    │   ├── handlers
    │   │   └── handlers.go
    │   ├── main.go
    │   └── parsetext
    │       └── parsetext.go
    └── resources
        ├── static
        │   └── style.css
        └── templates
            ├── index.html
            └── result.html
```

I have tried multiple ways to build an image and none of them were successful so far. Here are some of them.

```
FROM golang:1.19

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./

COPY *.go ./

RUN go build -o /app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/app" ]
```

```
FROM golang:1.19

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./

RUN go mod download

COPY src/go/main.go app/src/go
COPY src/go/handlers/*.go app/src/go/handlers
COPY src/go/parsetext/*.go app/src/go/parsetext
COPY src/resources/static/*.css app/src/resources/static
COPY src/resources/templates/*.html app/src/resources/templates

RUN go build -o /app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/app" ]
```

I would truly appreciate any help with this

Comment: Which one specific Dockerfile are you using?  What is going wrong, and is it going wrong when you build the image or run it?  What are the exact `docker` commands you're running, what errors are you getting, and if it's a runtime issue, what URL are you connecting to?

Answer (score 0):

I found two issues in your `Dockerfile`:

1. `COPY *.go ./`:

   It only copies `*.go` files in the current directory. I think you want to copy the whole directory like this: `COPY src/go ./src/go`
2. `RUN go build -o /app`:

   The specified build artifact `/app` conflicts with the directory created by `WORKDIR /app`. And I think that you should specify the package to build. I believe the correct one should be: `RUN go build -o theapp ./src/go` (change to artifact name `theapp` to whatever you like).

Here is the one that may work for you. And [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) is recommended.

```
# =============== build stage ===============
FROM golang:1.19 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./

RUN go mod download

COPY src/go ./src/go

RUN go build -o theapp ./src/go

# =============== final stage ===============
FROM debian:bullseye AS final

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

COPY --from=build /app/theapp ./
# Make sure the resources folder is copied to the correct place that your app expected.
COPY src/resources ./resources

CMD [ "/app/theapp" ]
```